# NSManagedObjectContext objectWithID lifecycle method (derived property)

Tags: multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have an `NSManagedObject` subclass with a transient property which is basically a reformatting of one of the persistent to-many relationships. I do this by observing the relationship with KVO and registering the observer in `-awakeFromFetch`, `-awakeFromInsert`, etc.

This all works fine, however if I pass the object between threads using the object's `objectID` and `-objectWithID:` technique there is no life-cycle method into which I can hook generation of the transient property. None of the life-cycle methods are triggered, in fact, since accessing the object directly using the id isn't considered a fetch, it seems.

There are ways around this, but it would be nice to use a life-cycle based technique. Am I perhaps missing something? Is there another standard method I could be using?

Thanks

Edit: Demonstration project
https://mega.co.nz/#!UsNBTZ7S!UU1qaFuc4W6Z2EYey-9AiMyfM8203Zfrm1lfpG5QITU

Answer (score 0):

When you have a `NSManagedObject` instance on one thread with a context and then retrieve it from a different thread and different context the `-awakeFromFetch` or `-awakeFromInsert` fires.

Are you using the contexts properly so that you are retrieving a new instance?

Have you looked at the pointers in the debugger to make sure you are talking to a new instance of the `NSManagedObject`?

In my experience those lifecycle methods fire per context.

Comment: Check my demonstration project: this shows the problem. Note that I'm am *not* performing a fetch request on the main thread, but using the object's identifier to load the object directly using `objectWithID:`. Note that `awakeFromInsert` is called on the initial insert, but `awakeFromFetch` is *not* called when the object is inserted into the main context with `objectWithID:`. And yes, they are separate object instances as expected. There appears to be no way to perform additional operations on the object when it is inserted into a context in this way...?

Comment: I am not able to download your demo app, it keeps timing out.  Can you repost it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so to answer my own question, the issue is caused because `objectWithID:` always returns an object, even though the object isn't registered in the receiver managed object context. Seems in some circumstances `objectRegisteredForID:` is more informative. In any case, the conclusion is that the life-cycle methods *do* fire, but to take care with `objectWithID:` since it can result in an inconsistent object.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same issue, and solved it by creating an extension on `NSManagedObjectContext` that goes through the normal fetch pathway, therefore triggering all of the expected lifecycle methods:

```
extension NSManagedObjectContext {
    func fetchObject<T: NSManagedObject>(with objectID: NSManagedObjectID) -> T? {
        let request = T.fetchRequest()

        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF = %@", objectID)
        guard let result = try? fetch(request) else {
            return nil
        }

        return result.first as? T
    }
}
```